# How to know the original url after url rewrite?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have url rewrite rules which redirect www.domain2.com to a subfolder under the root of a domain1.com (let's call this folder subproject). In my controller, I need to construct a URL to the original non modified path but the Request.Url properties (like AbsoluteUri or LocalPath) always contain the subproject subfolder.

In other words, if the user typed:

```
www.domain2.com/controller/action
```

urlrewrite makes it:

```
www.domain1.com/subproject/controller/action
```

and I wish to reconstruct the original url:

```
www.domain2.com/controller/action
```

I could hardcode the removal of subproject from the url and begin the url with domain2 but I need a generic piece of code because this url reconstruction will be in a reusable library. domain2 could be in the settings of my app but what about the subfolder?

In reference, here is the rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to subproject">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?domain2.com" />
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/subproject/" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="\subproject\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should be able to find it in [Request.RawUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.rawurl.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, it works. Out of curiosity, is the original domain lost or can I also retrieve it somewhere?

Comment: @Nicholas, I don't know of the top of my head, but I'm convinced that it *must* be somewhere in `Params`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params.aspx

Comment: Its actually in Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL"), I am sure Request.RawUrl just maps to that.  ;-)

Comment: @CrazyDart, yes, and `ServerVariables` are also in `Params` ;-)

Comment: @CrazyDart, after some googling, it seems HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL is non standard (I tried locally and it returns empty string). Using Reflector, I see that RawUrl looks into the CACHE_URL server variable (locally it works well and contains the original domain, but it's not in Params). Is it safe to use this one?

Comment: `string originalUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["CACHE_URL"];` Beware of the typo above where they use parentheses instead of square brackets.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a good way to get the current directory even when using rewrite.

I needed this to cache some resources in localStorage for an offline web app. With asp.net mvc, the page parameters are written as subdirecties under a page which causes the relative paths to change. Therefore, I needed the absolute path as a key for the resource in the localStorage.

Anyway, here it is:

```
        var applicationRoot = new System.Uri(Request.Url, Href("~"));
        var rawURl = Request.RawUrl;
        var rawUrlAbsolute = new System.Uri(serverRoot, rawURl);
        var relativeToCurrentPath = Href("SOMETHING_DOESNT_MATTER/../");
        var clientPathAbsolute = new System.Uri(rawUrlAbsolute, relativeToCurrentPath);
        var clientPathAbsoulteStr = clientPathAbsolute.AbsoluteUri;
```

This took me many attempts to figure out. Here is an example using my website:

#### The path without rewriter

```
    //  applicationRoot         = http://www.toldpro.com/
    //  rawURl                  = /Apps/GreekBible/App/A/B/C
    //  rawUrlAbsolute          = http://www.toldpro.com/Apps/GreekBible/App/A/B/C 
    //  relativeToCurrentPath   = ../../../
    //  clientPathAbsolute      = http://www.toldpro.com/Apps/GreekBible/
    //  clientPathAbsoulteStr   = http://www.toldpro.com/Apps/GreekBible/
```

#### The path rewriten to a subdomain

```
    //  applicationRoot         = http://greekbible.toldpro.com/Apps/GreekBible/
    //  rawURl                  = /App/A/B/C
    //  rawUrlAbsolute          = http://greekbible.toldpro.com/App/A/B/C 
    //  relativeToCurrentPath   = ../../../Apps/GreekBible/
    //  clientPathAbsolute      = http://greekbible.toldpro.com/Apps/GreekBible/
    //  clientPathAbsoulteStr   = http://greekbible.toldpro.com/Apps/GreekBible/
```

#### The rewrite rule:

For more information about this, the following is the rewrite rule I used:

```
// Rewrite: 
// http://greekbible.toldpro.com/App/* (Client)
// to
// http://www.toldpro.com/Apps/GreekBible/App/* (Actual)

    <rule name="Subdomain rewriter" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="App/(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.toldpro\.com$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^greekbible\.toldpro\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/Apps/GreekBible{URL}" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: This took me many hours to solve, so I thought someone could use it.