# c# get iis rewrite url

Tags: c#, iis, url-rewriting

I am using iis rewrite 2.0

URLs like this
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.aspx?article=1234
becomes
http://www.mywebsite.com/article/1234

In the C# I want to obtain this friendly URL, when I use

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

I get: http://www.mywebsite.com/index.aspx?article=1234

How do I get the friendly URL in my C#: http://www.mywebsite.com/article/1234?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know the original url after url rewrite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991552/how-to-know-the-original-url-after-url-rewrite)

Comment: thank you @CyrilDurand - that did indeed provide the answer i Need: HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Request.RawUrl instead of Request.Url. Request.RawUrl gives the original url that the user entered. Request.Url gives the url after being changed by the web server or aspnet routes.