# Url rewriting/routing on .Net Core with IIS and Cloudflare

Tags: iis, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, subdomain, cloudflare

A small introduction about the app's deployment & app in general:

We use .Net Core 6 MVC and is hosted in IIS. Additionally the application uses a domain which the actual website is hosted e.g. **[www.ExampleHost.com/ExampleApp](http://www.ExampleHost.com/ExampleApp)**.
Also we use **Cloudflare** to direct requests to a new domain for the website e.g. **[www.ExampleHost.com/ExampleApp](http://www.ExampleHost.com/ExampleApp)** -> **[www.Example-App.eu](http://www.Example-App.eu)**

Here is the problem, while the app works fine at [www.ExampleHost.com/ExampleApp](http://www.ExampleHost.com/ExampleApp), if we enter [www.Example-App.eu](http://www.Example-App.eu) the directory of the app appears in the Url like **[www.Example-App.eu/ExampleApp](http://www.Example-App.eu/ExampleApp)** in every request. That creates problem everywhere from returning Views to submitting Forms etc.

So an idea was to solve part of this problem by creating a web.config to configure URL Rewrite rules.

**web.config**

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RemoveExampleApp">
                    <match url=".*ExampleApp/(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="POST" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="RemoveExampleAppPost">
                    <match url=".*ExampleApp/(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="POST" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But we still unable to perform POST requests.

Additionally, I read to another Stack Overflow post that it is possible to configure/fix that by of using routing instead of rewrite rules but we had no luck with that.

[IIS URL Rewrite and .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48788866/iis-url-rewrite-and-net-core)

We are open to any suggestions.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can't u use url rewrite middleware

Comment: Hey Gauravsa, is there any major difference between configuring rewrite rules with web.config and rewrite middleware?

Comment: This document explains the difference between rewrite rules and rewrite middleware and how to use URL rewrite middleware in ASP.NET Core applications https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: I don't know about Cloudflare, but I wonder why you use Cloudflare to direct requests to a new domain for the website instead of using rewrite rules in IIS directly?

Comment: Well about the Cloudflare unfortunately that's the requirements, and the bad thing is that it adds extra complexity to the system.

Comment: When you type `www.Example-App.eu` in your browser, does the URL jump directly to `www.Example-App.eu/ExampleApp`? Do you see the 302 redirect code in the network of the browser console?

Comment: Well initially no but when I wanted to redirect myself to another page e.g. About , the URL would be www.Example-App.eu/ExampleApp/About/Index and would show Not Found Error, that's why we tried to use URL Rewrite rules in web.config to solve this problem.

Comment: You mean when you want to redirect the page to www.Example-App.eu/About/Index, but it will actually be redirected to www.Example-App.eu/ExampleApp/About/Index, right?

Comment: Please correct me if I misunderstood what you meant. If I understand correctly, I would like to know how you redirect the page to www.Example-App.eu/About/Index, what kind of rules are used?

Comment: Exactly, the rules we use are the above I show in the web.config, sorry if I overcomplicated the topic.

Comment: Please try to use FRT to trace rewrite rules, you can see how the rules are used internally. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules